# Is this even possible to create with a FSM?

Tags: finite-automata

I have a question that asks me to create  a finite state machine where it only accepts strings that end with a 1000 the issue is, I don't think this is possible because how can the FSM know when the string ends? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The FSM should just be in a terminal state after it sees `1000`, switching to a non-terminal state on additional input.

Comment: It needs to end in 1000, so like the string 001000 works, but the string 00100011 does not even though it contains 1000.

Comment: No problem.  When the FSM receives additional input, it transitions from an accepting state to a non-accepting state.